# Make MFC Program with Multiple Tabs

Tags: mfc

I want to make a MFC program with multiple tab, which each tab is assigned a dialog as this picture:
[image: This image is about multiple tab MFC]

Which MFC project should I create? How can I make these tabs and when I click that tab, a corresponding dialog will be opened.
For example, I have 2 dialog: IDC_VIEWER and IDC_UART. In MainFrm.cpp:

```
    CMultiDocTemplate* pNewDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(
        IDR_VIEWER_TMPL,
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CBaseDocument),
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame),
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CViewer));
    AddDocTemplate(pNewDocTemplate);

    CMultiDocTemplate* pNewDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(
        IDR_VIEWER_TMPL,
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CBaseDocument),
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame),
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CViewer));
    AddDocTemplate(pNewDocTemplate);
```

But these tap not link to to corresponding dialog.

Comment: Did you tried MDI (multi-document interface) ? With CView based on CFormView, where every document will have his own dialog template ...

Comment: I can not link tab to the corresponding dialog.

Comment: Sorry for delay ... you can consider to create a MDI, with more than one document type ... for everyone of them, you can use CView based on CFormView, everyone one them with a specific dialog template ... should be easy ...

Comment: You can find on net a lot of examples that used MDI with multimple document types ...

Comment: Also, check here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw2702d6(v=vs.90).aspx ... there, you can find a SDI project who use several dialog template to the same document ...